# Prevent SQL injection in EXECUTE ... INTO

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-12

I have a function that takes `ORDER BY` field and direction as parameters, and I'm trying to use the `format` function to interpolate them into the SELECT statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dummy_ordered_select(orderby text, orderdir text)
   RETURNS users AS
$$
DECLARE result_data users;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY %s %s', orderby, orderdir) INTO result_data;            
    RETURN NULL result_data;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I believe this is vulnerable to SQL injection (for instance, if `orderdir` is passed as `'ASC; DROP ALL TABLES;'`), is that correct?

I'd like to prevent it at the database level (the input values are sanitized in code, but I still worry about a possible attack vector if, for example, someone mistakenly skips the sanitization).

Note: this is just a sample function that does nothing but run a query, my actual function code that builds the query is more complex but doesn't contribute to the discussion.

Comment: Use `%I` instead of `%S` to force `quote_ident()` behavior.  Please see:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-QUOTE-LITERAL-EXAMPLE

Comment: What do you want to allow as input for `orderby`? Just simple column names like `'email'` and `'name'`, or also `'email DESC'` or even `'name ASC, email DESC'`?

Comment: @Bergi that was actually the most relevant part since the sort direction (`ASC` or `DESC`) to my knowledge can't be quoted, and I had omitted it. I've edited the question to include it.

Comment: @Esteban ok, if you're passing it as a separate parameter it's easy. Go with `%I` as Mike mentioned. Regarding direction, yes you cannot quote that keyword, so you should either validate it in your function (`CASE WHEN orderdir IN ('ASC', 'DESC') THEN orderdir END`) or use a boolean (ugly) or define your own enum

Answer (score 0):

Try using parameterized queries instead of using string interpolation.
Run this code, I used parameterized queries in it;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dummy_ordered_select(orderby text)
   RETURNS SETOF users AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY ' || quote_ident(orderby);
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: That is still string concatenation, there is no parameterised query here.

Comment: @Bergi - string concatenation there will be always - it is dynamic SQL. The important thing is sanitization of mutable string argument - in this case by `quote_ident`.

Comment: @PavelStehule Yes, but the answer falsely claims that this is a parameterised query not string concatenation.